# Post on the Wall Custom Control for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, custom-controls, vk

I'm trying to find a control that would have similar look and functionality like **Facebook** or **VK** Post on the Wall **Control**. It look like this:
[image]

[image]

**I don't need** to integrate my **app** with **Facebook** or **VK**. I need just a **similar** look and **functionality** to use it in my **app**. I try to search for something similar on **CocoaControls**. But I couldn't find anything, and, unfortunately I didn't have time to write my own control.

**Any ideas? Where can I find something similar to this?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the bar with the controls in it, that is above the keyboard?

If so, check out [Adding tool bar on top of the uikeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998134/adding-tool-bar-on-top-of-the-uikeyboard)