# UIKeyboard in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uikeyboard

I'm using Xcode 5 and the iOS7 SDK to build my app. I am wanting to make a sign in page very similar to that of the iOS7 eBay app.

So what I would like to do is this:

1. When the ViewController loads, I would like two UIButtons just above the keyboard
2. Once the user has finished entering their information and hitting the done button - the keyboard disappears and background animates very slightly to show a logo at the top.

I'm thinking I should be listening for UIKeyboard notifications and then do things based on that.

Here are my questions:

1. I am sure I can change the background image, based on the UIKeyboard notification status - how do I make it animate ? I don't want it to just appear?
2. How do I position the UIButtons correctly to sit by the keyboard ?

Comment: What u have tried to animate?

Comment: I used two different background - but its not really the effect I am after. If you look on the eBay app - once you press signed in, the UITextfields move down and the logo appears. that's what I am after really.

Comment: I am getting what u want. I am asking what u have tried (in code) to achieve that? And what problem u face in that?

Comment: Thanks. As I said, just flipped the background which was not good enough. I'll experiment some more and if I get stuck I will come back with a more specific question. Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `UIToolBar` and set it as inputaccessoryview to the textFields.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998134/adding-tool-bar-on-top-of-the-uikeyboard) is one clean & clear solution for this problem.

[Blog Post here](http://idebuggerman.blogspot.com/2010/08/uitoolbar-for-keyboard-with.html)

For backGround animation please use this.
May be you can set the background logo alpha = 0 initially.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
    self.view.logoImage.alpha = 1;
// make some more movements for anything that suits to your need.
// set frame of your textFields & any thing else that you need.

}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // may be you can load a new view controller here.
}];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you - that puts me in the right direction. I'll update when done.